# Entering multiple values using @setfield

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a text field/editable, allow multiple values, semicolon for both Multi-Value Options property, in which I want to save current user when they click a button. On the button I have the following code:

```
 @SetField("fieldA"; @Name([CN];@UserName));
```

The previous value always gets overwritten by the new. What would be the solution to have multiple values stored in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@SetField("fieldA"; fieldA:@Name([CN];@UserName));
```

That will append the current user's name to the item.

Comment: Additional Info: If fieldA is a Readers or Authors- Field, then @Name([CN] ; ... ) will in most cases not work...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using the @Unique function. Remember there's a 32K limit of summary field data, so don't let this list grow indefinitely. See @Subset function. Also, bear in mind that the user can save the document without clicking your button, so a Querysave event might be a better place to do this.